# Qt Multimedia - how to force read tags from media file

Tags: qt, qt5, meta-tags, qmediaplayer

It seems to be QMediaPlayer doesn't read tags of playlist files without of executing method play() of current track. Is there a way to force read tags from QMediaPlayer playlist without of playing it?

Sorry if this if a noob question, but I spent a lot of time for searches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste your time to use QMediaPlayer to read tags (this solution works good, but difficult for many files in list), simply use TagLib or another open-source library.

For example, 3 simple steps to use TagLib in Qt:

1.Compile taglib from source:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/taglib-1.9.1
$ cmake .
$ make
```

It's enough to deploy working instance of tag library. Really :)

2.Include headers and library in your project, simply add this or your custom path to project file:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/taglib-1.9.1/taglib/ -ltag
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/taglib-1.9.1/taglib/Headers
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/3rdparty/taglib-1.9.1/taglib/Headers
```

3.Use it, very simple function to get media tags from files, in this example artist and title of track:

```
    #include <fileref.h>
    #include <tag.h>
    QString gettags(QString mediafile){
        QString string;
        TagLib::FileRef file(mediafile.toUtf8());
        TagLib::String artist_string = file.tag()->artist();
        TagLib::String title_string = file.tag()->title();
        QString artist = QString::fromStdWString(artist_string.toWString());
        QString title = QString::fromStdWString(title_string.toWString());
        string = artist + " - " + title;
        return string;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current QT/OSX, use this project file snippet (change paths for your system)

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.11
LIBS += -L/Users/sir/prg.qt/TuneMerge/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/ -ltag -lz
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/sir/prg.qt/TuneMerge/taglib-1.11.1/
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/sir/prg.qt/TuneMerge/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/
INCLUDEPATH += /Users/sir/prg.qt/TuneMerge/taglib-1.11.1/taglib/toolkit/
DEPENDPATH += /Users/sir/prg.qt/TuneMerge/taglib-1.11.1/taglib
```